# Unable to access scope variable in jasmine test case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a controller defined in my module as follows,

```
myTestApp.controller("LoginController", function($scope,$http,$location) {

$scope.submitForm = function(){ 

    var userEmail = $scope.user.email;
    var userPassword = $scope.user.password;

    $http({
        url:'api/login/',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        method:'POST',
        data:{
            username:userEmail,
            password:userPassword
        }})
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.loginResult = data;
        });
     };   
});
```

I am trying to write a test case for mocking the HTTP call using `httpBackend`.

Here is my `jasmine` test code:

```
 describe('make HTTP mock call', function() {

var scope, httpBackend, http, controller;

beforeEach(module('myTestApp'));

describe('with httpBackend', function() {

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, $http) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        http = $http;
        controller = $controller('LoginController', {$scope : scope} );
        httpBackend.when("POST", "api/login/",{'username':'test@gmail.com', 'password':'test'}, function(headers) {
           return {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           };
        }).respond(200);
    }));

    afterEach(inject(function ($httpBackend){
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    }));

    it('to check if user is valid', inject(function ($http) {   

        var expectedResponse = { success: true };

        httpBackend.expectPOST('api/login/', {
            "username": "test@gmail.com",
            "password": "test"
        }, function(headers){
            return headers['Content-Type'] === 'application/json';
        }).respond(function(method, url, data, headers, params){
            return [200, {}, {}];
        });         

        //actual HTTP call
        $http({
        url:'api/login/',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        method:'POST',
        data:{
            username:"test@gmail.com",
            password:"test"
        }});

        //flush response
        httpBackend.flush();
        expect(scope.loginResult).toEqual(expectedResponse);
    }));    
  });
```

});

However, when I run the test case, I get the below error

> Expected undefined to equal Object({ success: true }).

I want to compare the response data from my HTTP call to the expectedResponse and if both are equal the test should pass.

However, I am not able to access the `$scope` variable loginResult from within my test case. can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong over here?

can someone describe the best way to mock the HTTP calls using Jasmine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your login data will actually be populated only when function `submitForm` will be called. So in the test, call the function before doing the `flush()` .

Update:
Make sure you have defined the

```
$scope.user={email :'test@gmail.com,password:'test'}
```

at the first line of your test (just after `it('to check if user is valid', inject(function ($http) {`)

Comment: hi when I call submitForm, i get error TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Comment: that's because in your scope, make sure you have defined the `$scope.user={email :'test@gmail.com,password:'test'}` at the first line of your test (just after `it('to check if user is valid', inject(function ($http) {  `).

Comment: @ParthDoshi you are welcome, will add the second part of solution to the original answer